# subexponential constant of Bernoulli

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, bernoulli-distribution

We say that a random variable $X$ is subexponential with constant $c$ if
$$ \mathbb{E}[\exp(t(X-p))] 
\le \exp(c^2t^2),
\qquad |t|\le 1/c.
$$

If instead the MGF were upper-bounded by $\exp(c^2t^2)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, we would be talking about the *subgaussian* constant, and for the Bernouilli $X\sim Ber(p)$; it is known that the optimal constant is
$
c^2=\frac{1-2p}{4\log((1-p)/p)}
$.

The optimal subexponential constant must be known as well; what is it?